# Using Google cloud in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

In my app i want to allow the user to backup the data to google docs. All my data were stored in sqlite file. How can i backup this data?

I looked in the Google API's page dedicated for [mobiles](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/mobile/more/#google-all), and I was unable to find out how to connect to google docs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the sql file to pdf file(Google doc supported file format) for storing in Google doc. For restore, i have download the same file and converted it to sql. I used Google API and follows the steps as in [this](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) blog.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

there are two way to do this .. one is using soap web service(Passing XML) and another one is called rest service (Passing URL) for accessing APi. First hit the login API using google account. later use XML or to do Remaining work.

Comment: Thanks. can i store a xml data into google docs? sorry im not that much exposed with google api's. can u give me a link for sample code?